# Overwrite files in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net

Whenever I save my Labels in my textfile for the first time it works fine.

Then when I edit something and try to save it again, it just puts all the things behind eachother.

I've searched but couldn't find a way to just overwrite the complete file, how do I do this? My current code is:

```
Dim file As System.IO.StreamWriter
    file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\Documenten\test.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine("Last Generated Child")
    file.WriteLine(Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine("All Available Parents")
    file.WriteLine(Parent1Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine(Parent2Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine(Parent3Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine(Parent4Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine(Parent5Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine(Parent6Code.Text)
    file.Close()
```

Another thing that would work is a way to overwrite specific lines.

Thanks :)

Comment: `File.WriteAllText` or `File.WriteAllLines`

Comment: You are trying to use legacy VB6 ways of handling files. I believe everything under `My.` is legacy VB6. Use `IO.File` instead.

Comment: @Neolisk I think you're thinking of `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Compatibility`. `My` is something else: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/195450/do-you-use-the-my-namespace-in-vb-net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The method [OpenTextFileWriter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms128023%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has the capability to append to prexistent text in the file or overwrite everything with new data.

You are using the `Append` parameter set to True.
So every time you write to your file, the text is appended to the current content of the file.

If you want to overwrite then just change

```
file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\Documenten\test.txt", False)
```

Also, I suggest to enclose your StreamWriter in a [Using statement block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/htd05whh%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to ensure a correct closing and disposing of your stream

```
Using file = My.Computer.FileSystem.OpenTextFileWriter("D:\Documenten\test.txt", True)
    file.WriteLine("Last Generated Child")
    file.WriteLine(Code.Text)
    file.WriteLine("All Available Parents")
    .....
End Using
```