# How to get text data from an url file with visual basic

Tags: visual-studio-2015, basic

I'm trying to read and save a text file from an URL (api.ivao.aero/getdata/whazzup/whazzup.txt) with Visual Basic but I couldn't find the syntax to download it. It even will be enough if I can read this text and write it to a TextBox. (Visual Studio 2015)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be done.

Import these :

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Net
```

Then try this:

```
Dim address As String = "http://api.ivao.aero/getdata/whazzup/whazzup.txt"
Dim client As WebClient = New WebClient()
Dim reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(client.OpenRead(address))
Textbox2.Text = reader.ReadToEnd
```

The text from the url will be displayed/read in textbox2. To have better idea/knowledge about using StreamReader to Read Text from Files, you may read this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw67h925.aspx).
Hope it helps.

Comment: Glad to hear that. U are welcome :-) Accept the answer if it looks ok to you.

Comment: It is completely ok. But I have a problem when writing. I used richtextbox but I can't write new lines. Reading is ok but when it comes to writing, there is no new lines in txt file

Comment: There's is a question about your other problem on SO. You may want to have a look at it :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20163743/overwrite-files-in-visual-basic