# VB.Net My.Computer won't work on a Module

Tags: vb.net

I wonder if anyone can help?

I'm not able to use My.Computer in a visual studio 2013 module when developing a formless application. This command has worked fine for windows form applications but the module will not allow it. I've done all the basic things, like importing System.IO, and spent far too long comparing references to the form and switching properties. I wonder if anyone has faced this problem before and overcome it?

Thank you in advance!

Best wishes,
Sarah

Comment: the namespace is `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices`  but that is just a wrapper for NET methods and objects.  Also, by "formless app" do you mean a console application?

Comment: Thanks user3697824 :) making it a console application solved the problem. It started as a windows form app originally but was modified to become formless which was causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You must ensure a reference to `Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll` is added to the project. For more details you may refer

[MSDN reference to My.Computer Object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/11bxex12(v=vs.120).aspx) and
[MSDN reference to Microsoft.VisualBasic.Devices Namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualbasic.devices(v=vs.100).aspx)

Also this SO post may be helpful [do-you-use-the-my-namespace-in-vb-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195450/do-you-use-the-my-namespace-in-vb-net)

Comment: Was looking at your suggestions before asking Stack Overflow for help. Thank you for looking into it for me :)