# Access MDI Parent StatusStrip in Child Window VB.NET 2015

Tags: vb.net

VB.NET 2015 -- Have placed StatusStrip control  with 2 ToolStripStatusLabel on it in a MDI window. when i open a new form, this would be the Child of the MDI window.

How do i read from info ToolStripStatusLabel.

For Each does not loop through all items in StatusStrip, and from what i have learnt, ToolStripStatusLabel is not a Control as such so the For each loop does not work.

Me.Owner.Controls also does not work to access ToolStripStatusLabel for the same reason as above

What to Do ?

Comment: Why would you use `Me.Owner`? How did you make the child form a child form in the first place? You set the `MdiParent` property, right? So it should be obvious that you use `Me.MdiParent` to access the MDI parent. You can cast that as its actual type (rather than just `Form`) and then access all its members, including the `StatusStrip`.

Comment: That said, that's not really the appropriate way to do it. Ideally, if the child form needs data from the parent form, it would raise an event. The parent form then handles that event and sets a property of the `e` parameter, which the child form can then read. That way, the child form doesn't have to know anything specific about the parent form. Also, the data should not be coming from a `StatusStrip`. The parent form should have the original data that was used to set the label text stored somewhere and that is the data that should be passed to the child. I'll post an answer to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way for any child form to get data from its parent is for the child form to raise an event and the parent form to pass the data back to the child via the event args. This way, the child never has to know anything specific about the parent form so, in theory, many different parent forms could display the same child form and pass it data. This is an example of loose coupling.

The child form would look something like this, providing an event that is raised when it needs data and it gets that data back via the custom `EventArgs` object that it created:

```vb
Public Class Form2

    Public Event StatusDataNeeded As EventHandler(Of StatusDataNeededEventArgs)

    Protected Overridable Sub OnStatusDataNeeded(e As StatusDataNeededEventArgs)
        RaiseEvent StatusDataNeeded(Me, e)
    End Sub

    Private Sub GetStatusData()
        Dim e As New StatusDataNeededEventArgs

        OnStatusDataNeeded(e)

        MessageBox.Show(e.StatusData)
    End Sub

    '...

End Class


Public Class StatusDataNeededEventArgs

    Public Property StatusData As String

End Class
```

As you can see, there's no reliance on any specific type of parent form there and there's also no reliance on this form being an MDI child. It simply raises its event and anyone listening can provide the status data, no matter the relationship.

In your case, the MDI parent form might look something like this:

```vb
Public Class Form1

    'Stores the data that will be displayed in the StatusStrip.
    Private statusData As String

    'Display the status data in the StatusStrip.
    Private Sub SetStatusText()
        ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text = statusData
    End Sub

    'Create and display a child form.
    Private Sub DisplayChildForm()
        Dim childForm As New Form2 With {.MdiParent = Me}

        'Handle the event raised when the child requires the status data.
        AddHandler childForm.StatusDataNeeded, AddressOf ChildForm_StatusDataNeeded

        childForm.Show()
    End Sub

    'Pass the status data to the child form.
    Private Sub ChildForm_StatusDataNeeded(sender As Object, e As StatusDataNeededEventArgs)
        e.StatusData = statusData
    End Sub

    '...

End Class
```

As you can see, the status data is stored in its own field. The `StatusStrip` is for display of status data, not storage. The parent form creates and displays a child form and handles the event. In the event handler, it simply passes the status data to the property of the `e` parameter.

To learn more about creating your own events, see [here](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2009/11/defining-and-raising-custom-events.html).

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response, i will try this out and get back

Answer (score 1):

The Event approach by jmcilhinney is definitely a better way however as a quick solution the `My` Namespace can be used in VB.Net.

```
My.Forms.<Form Name>.<Control name>.<property>
```

eg:

```
My.Forms.AM_MDI.ToolStripStatusLabel1.Text
```

> For those who would love read more on  My Namespace -
> Namespaces in VB.NET
> https://www.thoughtco.com/namespaces-in-vbnet-3424445

> Do you use the 'My' namespace in VB.NET?
> [Do you use the 'My' namespace in VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/195450/do-you-use-the-my-namespace-in-vb-net)

Comment: I actually prefer this and MdiParent to the Event method Jim shows only when it comes to Control. Jim's experienced to know it's best to separate the logic from the presentation layer. That way he can test the logic without mocking any GUI controls.